# Replace all values from one pandas dataframe to another without extra columns

Tags: pandas

These are my two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'],'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['falcon', 'dog'],'num_legs': [4, 2],'num_wings': [0, 2],'num_specimen_seen': [2, 10]})
```

When I use left join , this is the result:

```
merge = df1.merge(df2, on='animal', how='left')
```

```
Output:

animal  num_legs_x  num_wings_x num_specimen_seen_x num_legs_y  num_wings_y num_specimen_seen_y
falcon      2          2                 10            4            0              2
dog         4          0                  2            2            2              10
spider      8          0                  1            NaN          NaN             NaN
fish        0          0                  8            NaN          NaN             NaN
```

I am looking for an output like this , where row 1 and 2 values are replaced by values coming from df2 :

```
animal  num_legs    num_wings   num_specimen_seen   
falcon      4           0              2
dog         2           2              10
spider      8           0              1            
fish        0           0              8
```

I attempted using `np.where` but couldnt write something correctly

```
df = np.where(df1.animal == df2.animal, ?, ?)
```

Maybe left join isnt correct way to achieve what I want. I am new to pandas , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why would `falcon` have `4` in the final output? I don't understand how the numbers in your final output are computed

Comment: not sure if you're after something such as `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).groupby("animal").sum().reset_index()`

Comment: @baxx falcon has 4 because I want its values to be replaced during merge with data coming from df2.

Comment: So - anything that's in df1 and df2 should be replaced by the value from df2, that's correct?

Comment: On the common key,  yes

Comment: ok cool - you have a nice answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `update`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('animal')
df1.update(df2.set_index('animal'))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1
   animal  num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
0  falcon       4.0        0.0                2.0
1     dog       2.0        2.0               10.0
2  spider       8.0        0.0                1.0
3    fish       0.0        0.0                8.0
```

Comment: Is `set_index` and `reset_index` required? Wouldn't `df1.update(df2)` work?

Comment: @student what I do here is use the animal as index to match the value, if without set_index, we are doing the assignment by the default index range index, which may cause the mismatch ~

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I forgot about mismatch when animal column do not match,